# Which type of coin is which?

Tags: understanding

> The type of the receiving coin, upon which another set of dies are
>   struck, is referred to as "undertype", while the type being struck
>   over it is called an "overtype". ([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=efaOR_-YsIcC&pg=PA81&dq=what%20is%20counterstrike%20of%20coin&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOse-B4JHdAhXBsaQKHdeKDcIQuwUIKjAA#v=onepage&q=what%20is%20counterstrike%20of%20coin&f=false))

Am I understanding correctly?:

- "undertype" is the original coin.
- "overtype" is the original coin which counterstruck by another set of dies.

Comment: This is technical language, and its meaning is not clear to me as a native English speaker. I can guess what it means, but it uses words outside their normal meanings.

Comment: Please tell me what do you guess.

Comment: I didn't put my guess, because Helen had already given a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right according to this [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=Pq2iCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=undertype%20vs%20overtype%20coin&source=bl&ots=_HJASOu986&sig=QqCASTSF2uKqA1YUP9I3zvuOH14&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjx4vj2_pHdAhVIqIsKHVluCtwQ6AEwCXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=undertype%20vs%20overtype%20coin&f=false):

> Counter-striking is the phenomenon of coins issued by one authority
>   being re-struck by another authority. Numismatists refer to the
>   **original strike of counter-struck coins** as the **'undertype'** and the **new** one as the **'overtype'**. When properly done, re-striking can completely erase the original undertype.